# How to encode an ArrayList<Complex Object> to json in an Android application and post it to a Java REST web service?

Tags: android, rest, json

I need to know how to encode an object of type `ArrayList<Complex Object>` to json format in an Android application and how to post the encoded json string to a REST web service that consumes json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the arraylist as it is to jsonobject with key.

Comment: After seeing this answer, I googled for "add arraylist to json object" as you said and I found what I exactly need in this link to an old question in Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848601/arraylistobject-json , so thanks for your help Amrut.